# Python Console: Detect Ctrl X Key Press Event

Tags: python, python-3.x, keypress

I want to detect if Ctrl + X is clicked so that I can exit my Python application. I don't know how to do it? Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of application? Command line or gui based?

Comment: @alex As of now, I have a command line program.

Comment: Standard behaviour on linux and macos is to stop things in the command line with Ctrl+C. Why do you want to switch to Ctrl+X?

Comment: @Alex -- Because it is a requirement of our teacher as pat of our assignment.

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a function like the ones discussed here? [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Or maybe you could use curses.

Either way you would just need to find the key code for ctrl-X, it's 24.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and the best option is to use the module [**`keyboard`**](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/). Install it using `pip install keyboard`.
Use the following code at the start of your code:

```
import keyboard as k
k.add_hotkey("ctrl+x",lambda: quit())

#Your code....
```

Well, it works easily, but, it will read keys from the whole windows. For example the program is running and you are using notepad currently and you pressed <kbd>ctrl+x</kbd> , then the python program will close too.

Comment: Requires ROOT ... `raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")`

Comment: @YzmirRamirez Are you using linux?